# select only top record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have `SQL` like this

```
SELECT manjalink_id, printed_serial, full_name, vm.cu_id
from [dbfastsconfigdataref].[dbo].[v_manja_user_cuid] vm
INNER JOIN dbmanjaprofile.dbo.m_manja_user m on m.manjalink_id = 
vm.manja_user_id
INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_micard mi on mi.cu_id = vm.cu_id
where m.created_timestamp >= '2018-02-01'
order by m.created_timestamp, full_name
```

with output

```
    Manjalink_id       printed_serial     full_name      cu_id
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
        101              00000123          alex          5556566
        102              00000124          alex          5556899
        103              00000126          max           8989899
```

and I would like to be like this:

```
 Manjalink_id       printed_serial     full_name      cu_id
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
        101              00000123          alex          5556566
        103              00000126          max           8989899
```

How to get the result as the desired output?

Thanks!

Comment: Use Row_Number() with partition you will find so many reference here

Comment: You didn't alias the fields in the query, it is hidden which field comes from which table. A simple solution would be a grouping on full_name getting min(manjalink_id) and min(printed_serial) which sound to be incremental values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something like this .

**Use Row_number()** to generate a sequence number based on your columns and pick the required Sequence values .

```
select manjalink_id, printed_serial, full_name, cu_id  from (
SELECT manjalink_id, printed_serial, full_name, vm.cu_id ,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by full_name order by manjalink_id) Rnum
from [dbfastsconfigdataref].[dbo].[v_manja_user_cuid] vm
INNER JOIN dbmanjaprofile.dbo.m_manja_user m on m.manjalink_id = 
vm.manja_user_id
INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_micard mi on mi.cu_id = vm.cu_id
where m.created_timestamp >= '2018-02-01'
)as a
where Rnum=1
```

**Note :** For your reference check [Row_number()](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/308281/How-to-Use-ROW-NUMBER-to-Enumerate-and-Partition-R) .And also there are lot many websites to learn about it

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT manjalink_id, printed_serial, full_name, cu_id
from
(SELECT manjalink_id, printed_serial, full_name, vm.cu_id, row_number() over (partition by full_name order by manjalink_id) rn
from [dbfastsconfigdataref].[dbo].[v_manja_user_cuid] vm
INNER JOIN dbmanjaprofile.dbo.m_manja_user m on m.manjalink_id = 
vm.manja_user_id
INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_micard mi on mi.cu_id = vm.cu_id
where m.created_timestamp >= '2018-02-01'
) a where rn = 1
order by full_name
```